# how to redirect from /signin-oidc back to my controller/action?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

the callback url is https://localhost:44338/signin-oidc

lets say i am in controller/action , decorated with    [Authorize]

how do i redirect from https://localhost:44338/signin-oidc  back to my controller/action ?

Note : I am following the wiki :
[Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample)

Answer (score 7):

You can store the url on server side . For example ,base on code sample :

[Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample)

modify your OIDC configurations like :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
        {
            //save url to state
            n.ProtocolMessage.State = n.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToString();
        },

        OnTokenValidated =  ctx =>
        {
            var url = ctx.ProtocolMessage.GetParameter("state");
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("myurl", url)
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            //add url to claims
            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

        OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
        {
            var url = ctx.Principal.FindFirst("myurl").Value;
            ctx.ReturnUri = url;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }



    };
    // Per the code below, this application signs in users in any Work and School
    // accounts and any Microsoft Personal Accounts.
    // If you want to direct Azure AD to restrict the users that can sign-in, change 
    // the tenant value of the appsettings.json file in the following way:
    // - only Work and School accounts => 'organizations'
    // - only Microsoft Personal accounts => 'consumers'
    // - Work and School and Personal accounts => 'common'

    // If you want to restrict the users that can sign-in to only one tenant
    // set the tenant value in the appsettings.json file to the tenant ID of this
    // organization, and set ValidateIssuer below to true.

    // If you want to restrict the users that can sign-in to several organizations
    // Set the tenant value in the appsettings.json file to 'organizations', set
    // ValidateIssuer, above to 'true', and add the issuers you want to accept to the
    // options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers collection
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
});
```

Comment: hi Nan, Thanks for the info !

i hit the breakpoint 
            n.ProtocolMessage.State = n.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToString();


but my code is still running  in the redirect url from OIDC .
in this code, i am able to retrieve the token :             var accessToken = HttpContext.Request.Form["id_token"];

do I somehow need to cause    OnTokenValidated  or       OnTicketReceived  event?

Comment: @user1224643,  yes, the redirect url is the original one , you need to get url from `OnTokenValidated ` event and set redirect url(your action) in `OnTicketReceived ` event .

Comment: hi Nan,i reach  OnRedirectToIdentityProvider   , and then I reach  relative path in appsettings  "CallbackPath": " . But  I don't i reach   OnTokenValidated  breakpoint .  the Auth is triggered by     [Authorize] decoration of a controller. Do i need something else in order to reach OnTokenValidated  ?

Comment: hi Nan, i started a new thread   asking about OnTokenValidated breakpoint not reached. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807290/openidconnectevents-ontokenvalidated-not-being-reached

Comment: We spent days trying to figure out why our Azure Application Gateway was breaking the redirect from inside the signin-oidc page. Setting the ReturnUri on the OnTicketReceived did the trick!